# Do I need to pass a worksheet as ByRef or ByVal?

Tags: vba, excel, pass-by-reference

I broke out some code from a larger block and need to pass a worksheet to it...

I'm not assigning any new value to the worksheet, but I am making changes to the Page Break settings for that sheet.  Do I need to pass it as ByRef, or is ByVal good enough?

```
Private Sub SetPageBreaks(ByRef wsReport As Worksheet)
Dim ZoomNum As Integer

  wsReport.Activate
  ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
  ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
  ZoomNum = 85
  With ActiveSheet
    Select Case wsReport.Name
      Case "Compare"
        Set .VPageBreaks(1).Location = Range("AI1")
        ZoomNum = 70
      Case "GM"
        .VPageBreaks.Add before:=Range("X1")
      Case "Drift"
        .VPageBreaks.Add before:=Range("T1")
      Case Else
        .VPageBreaks.Add before:=Range("U1")
    End Select
  End With
  ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
  ActiveWindow.Zoom = ZoomNum

End Sub
```

Comment: this may help http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/ron/objects.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either will work, but for semantically correct code, prefer passing it by value (`ByVal`).

When you pass an object variable by value, you're passing *a copy* of the *pointer* to the object.

So what the procedure is working with *is* the same object (i.e. changed property values *will* be seen by the caller), except it's not allowed to `Set` the pointer to something else - well it *can*, but it'll do that on *its own copy* and so the caller won't be affected.

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim target As Worksheet
    Set target = ActiveSheet
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(target)
    DoSomethingElse target
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(target)
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomethingElse(ByVal target As Worksheet)
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(target)
    Set target = Worksheets("Sheet12")
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(target)
    'in DoSomething, target still refers to the ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

On the other hand...

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim target As Worksheet
    Set target = ActiveSheet
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(target)
    DoSomethingElse target
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(target)
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomethingElse(ByRef target As Worksheet)
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(target)
    Set target = Worksheets("Sheet12")
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(target)
    'in DoSomething, target now refers to Worksheets("Sheet12")
End Sub
```

In general, parameters should be passed by value. It's just an unfortunate language quirk that `ByRef` is the default (VB.NET fixed that).

The same is true for non-object variables:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim foo As Long
    foo = 42
    DoSomethingElse foo
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomethingElse(ByVal foo As Long)
    foo = 12
    'in DoSomething, foo is still 42
End Sub
```

And...

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim foo As Long
    foo = 42
    DoSomethingElse foo
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomethingElse(ByRef foo As Long)
    foo = 12
    'in DoSomething, foo is now 12
End Sub
```

If a variable is passed by reference, but is never reassigned in the body of a procedure, then it can be passed by value.

If a variable is passed by reference, and reassigns it in the body of a procedure, then that procedure could likely be written as a `Function`, and actually *return* the modified value instead.

If a variable is passed by value, and is reassigned in the body of a procedure, then the caller isn't going to see the changes - which makes code suspicious; if a procedure needs to reassign a `ByVal` parameter value, the intent of the code becomes clearer if it defines its own local variable and assigns *that* instead of the `ByVal` parameter:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim foo As Long
    foo = 42
    DoSomethingElse foo
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomethingElse(ByVal foo As Long)
    Dim bar As Long
    bar = foo
    '...
    bar = 12
    '...
End Sub
```

---

These are all actual code inspections in [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/), as VBE add-in I'm heavily involved with, that can analyze your code and see these things:

[image: ByVal parameter is assigned]

> *Parameter is passed by value, but is assigned a new value/reference. Consider making a local copy instead if the caller isn't supposed to know the new value. If the caller should see the new value, the parameter should be passed ByRef instead, and you have a bug.*
>
> <sub>http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/AssignedByValParameterInspection</sub>

[image: Procedure can be written as a function]

> *A procedure that only has one parameter passed by reference that is assigned a new value/reference before the procedure exits, is using a ByRef parameter as a return value: consider making it a function instead.*
>
> <sub>http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ProcedureCanBeWrittenAsFunctionInspection</sub>

[image: Parameter can be passed by value]

> *A parameter that is passed by reference and isn't assigned a new value/reference, could be passed by value instead.*
>
> <sub>http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ParameterCanBeByValInspection</sub>

That's the case of `wsReport` here:

[image: Parameter 'wsReport' can be passed by value]

Comment: I use Rubberduck, and that is what prompted me to think about the question.  While the worksheet variable was never assigned a new value (ByVal would be fine), the fact that changes were being made to the sheet (changes would normally require ByRef) made me wonder if ByVal was the best practice for passing an object.

Comment: Hi Mathieu. Are you saying that for Worksheets and any other Office objects, what is actually happening is that the reference is made to an object which itself points to the Worksheet? So that in essence what we pass `ByVal MyVar as Worksheet` is not a copy of the Worksheet object to which `MyVar` would point, but a copy of an intermediate object? And so `MyVar` points to that intermediate object, which itself points to the Worksheet?

Comment: @Ama there's no *intermediate object*.. what I'm saying is that there's a difference between an object and a *pointer* to that object - what gets copied or passed around is the pointer, not the object.

Comment: Shoot I always wrongly had in mind the objects were copied and ByVal carried a pointer pointing to that new object. So in effect ByVal only protects against modifying a data type... All these years! That says a lot on how often you would modify an object form inside a sub/function taking that same object as an argument.. Gonna have to run some testings.. thanks!

Comment: ^^ this post was a light bulb moment for me as well +