# Excel VBA - How to use ByVal

Tags: vba, excel

Someone at code review was helping optimize my code and said I should be using the following code to avoid duplicate code.  I'm not sure how to use it properly...From what I can tell I have to type in ConvertToNumeric when I want the code to run but I'm not sure how to change the variables like which sheet or which column to find the last cell on.  The concept makes sense to me though.

```
    Private Sub ConvertToNumeric(ByVal sheetToUse As Worksheet, ByVal columnToFindLastCellOn As String)
        Dim helperCell As Range
        Set helperCell = sheetToUse.Range("AK1")
            helperCell.Value = "1"
            helperCell.Copy

        Dim lastCell As Range
        Set lastCell = sheetToUse.Cells(Rows.Count, columnToFindLastCellOn).End(xlUp)

        Dim modifyRange As Range
        Set modifyRange = sheetToUse.Range(lastCell, lastCell.End(xlUp))
        modifyRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        helperCell.ClearContents
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need a better understanding of when and how to use `ByRef` and `ByVal`. There are [many](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1004%20ByVal%20ByRef.shtml) [good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41813615/4717755) [explanations](http://excelmatters.com/2016/03/10/byval-or-byref-whats-the-difference/) of their uses.

Comment: Where you saying you don't understand how to use the sub? An example would be `ConvertToNumeric(wsh,colNum)` where `wsh` is a variable with a worksheet object, and `colNum` is a String with the column number(?).

Comment: The answer you got over at CR *does* include calls to `ConvertToNumeric`. Feel free to comment on that answer for clarifications from the author, if needed.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon unfortunately CR says I need 50 rep to comment on anything so I couldn't respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the sub mentioned at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193007/format-2-excel-sheets-then-save-both-sheets-as-a-new-workbook/193024#193024) you can call it like this

```
ConvertToNumeric Worksheets(2), "A"
```

or

```
ConvertToNumeric Worksheets("Sheet1"), 3
```

---

- `sheetToUse` is the sheet you want to work with
- `columnToFindLastCellOn` is the column letter (or number) that the last used cell is based on

Comment: Or like `Call ConvertToNumeric(Worksheets("Sheet1"), 3)` to make it easier to find the calls in the code (since the `Call` keyword turns blue)

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I was misusing seems like.  I was doing ConvertToNumeric(ByVal "Sheet2",ByVal "A").

Comment: @Mistella technically true, however `Call` gets annoying when it's used or omitted arbitrarily/inconsistently. People do `Call DoSomething`, but then they do `MsgBox "hello"` - yet both are "calls". `helperCells.ClearContent` is also a "call", as is `modifyRange.PasteSpecial`, yet we never see those using a `Call` keyword for some reason. IMO if you need syntax highlighting to identify calls, then your code likely has other readability issues. Rule of thumb, any executable instruction will include a "call" to something.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I usually use `Call` for custom subs/functions, because I tend to forget about the search/find (ctrl+f, I know) and look for calls to custom subs by scrolling....