# Using ByRef to update recordset fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way to update fields in a recordset via ByRef function? I feel like this example *should* work, but tbl![Field1] does not get updated by the UpdateTable sub.  Can this be done, or do I have to pass the field to a variable first?

```
Private Sub DeclareTable()
    Dim tbl As Recordset
    Set tbl = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1")
    tbl.MoveFirst
    
    tbl.Edit
    UpdateTable tbl![field1], 5, 2
    tbl.Update
    
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateTable(ByRef tblField, X, Y)
    tblField = X * Y
End Sub
```

Comment: This works for me, make sure your table and field names are correct

Comment: I just double-checked. Stepped through the DeclareTable sub. tbl![field1] pulls an existing value of 25 from Table1.  tblField receives 25 and returns as 10, but tbl![field1] never changes.
Maybe you have different default settings for .OpenRecordset?

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: You do not need byref to update a field or any other object. The parameter must be declared `ByVal tblField As Field`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to be more specific as you wish to use DAO:

```vb
Private Sub DeclareTable()

    Dim tbl     As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set tbl = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1")
    tbl.MoveFirst
    
    tbl.Edit
    UpdateTable tbl![Field1], 5, 2
    tbl.Update
    
    tbl.Close
    
End Sub


Private Sub UpdateTable( _
    ByVal tblField As DAO.Field, _
    ByVal X As Long, _
    ByVal Y As Long)

    tblField.Value = X * Y

End Sub
```

This runs nicely here.

Comment: Declaring "As Field" solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: There is really no need to have `ByRef`.

Comment: @GSerg, the reason is to explicitly tell, that you haven't forgotten a `ByVal`.

Comment: @Gustav There must be `byval` in this case.

Comment: @GSerg, it is not a must, though, in this case, you can. However, you should normally always pass objects by reference.

Comment: @Gustav Absolutely not. You [should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41813615/11683) always pass objects byval, unless there is a specific reason not to. You will find that there is almost never such reason.

Comment: @GSerg: You are right. It's not the object that's modified here, a property (Value) of it only. Thanks for the link to the excellent explanation by Mathieu.